# How to send audio file using telethon so that the audio can be played in in-app media player for mobile?

Tags: telethon

I've tried to use both function, the audio still cannot be played in-**app media player**

`await client.send_file(chat, '/my/songs/song.mp3', voice_note=True)`

`await client.send_file(chat, '/my/songs/song.mp3', attributes=[DocumentAttributeFilename(file_name=fileName + '.mp3'), DocumentAttributeAudio(duration=100, voice=True)])`

Comment: Are you looking to send an audio or a voice note? Also what you mean by "the audio can't be played in in-app media player", does it give you any error?

Comment: I'm looking to send an audio which can be played using in-app audio player. No error at all. The audio file is sent successfully but cannot be played using in-app audio player. 

Here's the reference for in-app audio player in telegram.
https://telegram.org/blog/live-locations#new-media-player

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking to send an audio which can be played using in-app audio
>   player.

Ok, you just need to use `send_file`, reference on the library docs [here](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.uploads.UploadMethods.send_file).

```
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient

client = TelegramClient('SESSION_NAME', 'YOUR_API_ID', 'YOUR_API_HASH')
client.start(phone=+xxxxxxxxxxxx)

async def main():
    await client.send_file('me', 'test.mp3')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: I've used send_file already. But when I clicked to play, it plays like that https://imgur.com/gallery/AtY5aZu but not in the audio player which can play in background.

Answer (score 0):

client.send_file(chat, '/my/songs/song.mp3', voice_note=True)

test this, its send audio as user record, without "voice_note=True", media sended as main file

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still having this problem, but I solved it by installing the hachoir module with `pip install hachoir`. Basically the problem is that the client doesn't have the necessary metadata

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation as the author cause of my mp3-file had no extension (I used temporary file).

The reasons of your situation you can find in `send_file` method code. In my case, I discovered that if I set mime-type `audio/mpeg` for my media inside `send_file/self._file_to_media` in a debug mode, it sends file as in-app audio. So I found out that that method can't guess my file mime-type. I searched ahead and found my solution.

And... I tried `voice_note=True` - in my case it did not help, because my file was not a voice, but an mp3. And, actually, when I downloaded it it has `voice_note=False` set. So setting `voice_note` to `True` has no meaning if you are handling audio-files which are not voices.